# how to replace a character in an array using numpy?

Tags: python

I have an array that consists of numeric values that are on a string form along with the '?' character which represents missing values. How can I make to replace those chars with an outlier value like -999999?

I know there is a way with Panda´s, but how to do that only using numpy? Tried to find those values with something like:

```
x=X[X=='?']
```

to use numpy replace, but no luck at all. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite similar to the Pandas method:

```
X[X == '?'] = '-999999'
```

at which point, if you desire, you could convert the values to integers using

```
X = X.astype(int)
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(['1', '2', '3', '?', '5'], dtype=object)
X[X == '?'] = '-999999'
X = X.astype(int)
print(X)
# array([      1,       2,       3, -999999,       5])
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be using [numpy.place](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html) :

```
np.place(X,X=="?",-999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print(np.where(X == '?', '-999999', X).astype(int))
```